# How to access a ManyToManyField between two apps using ContentTypes for Django admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Say I have this app named Pantry that is to connect to any other app I may come along. To keep the app decoupled, generic relations are used through the model LinkedItem which connects the Ingredients model to apps outside Pantry.

I can make a filter_horizontal show up for the LinkedItem's admin in Django. Now I would like the content on the other end of the generic relation, say an app named Bakery, to be able to do a filter_horizontal with ingredients.

**Pantry**
*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import fields

class Ingredient(models.Model):
   '''
   Model containing all the ingredients, their slugs, and their descriptions
   '''
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

   # method to return the name of the db entry
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class LinkedItem(models.Model):
   '''
   Model that links ingredients to various other content models
   '''
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = fields.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

   ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

   # method to return the name of the db entry
   def __str__(self):
      return self.ingredient.name

   # defines options for the model itself
   class Meta:
     unique_together = (('content_type','object_id'))    # prevents duplicates
```

**Bakery**
*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from bakery.models import Cake

class CakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   filter_horizontal = ('') # what to put here so ingredients show up?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you figured out anything about how to implement these scenarios?

Comment: @DipakChandranP I did recently figure out a way to do this. Just added an answer with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a [GenericTabularInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) for LinkedItem and putting some restrictions on the display to avoid duplicates like below:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.admin import GenericTabularInline

class LinkedItemAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = LinkedItem

    # choosing the field and display
    field = ['ingredient']
    filter_horizontal = ['ingredient']

    # These help with removing some potential issues in the admin
    extra = 0
    min_num = 1
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False
```

Then in the CakeAdmin I can do this to make the ingredients show up.

```
class CakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [LinkedItemAdmin]
```

Comment: Yup, somewhat helpful for my scenario too. Thanks. :)